# Get $mailer's html

Tags: magento-1, email, email-templates

In `/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` +/- line 1263 `public function sendNewOrderEmail()`

It uses `$mailer` to send the mail.

I would like to get the HTML content that is in the email send by `$mailer`.
For example with: `$mailer->toHtml()`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try `$text = $mailer->getProcessedTemplate($variables);` where $variables is an array which is to be replaced in template. 
If you do not have the variables or want to get the text content of the mail after it is sent, then you can do `$mail = $mailer->getMail(); $text = $mail->getBodyHtml();` where $email is instance of Zend_Mail, which yo can look into to see what else you can get.

Comment: Thanks Petar, but I'm not sure I understand. I've tried (after: `$mailer->send();`) all your options but also: `$mailer->getBodyText()->getRawContent()` and it's not giving any output... Anymore hints where to look for...? thanks!

Comment: You should get $mail object out of mailer, and from $mail take $mail->getBodyText()

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get it :-S
I have `$mailer->send();` then `$mail = $mailer->getMail();` and then `$mail->getBodyText();` and `$mail->getBodyText()` = empty. Thank!

Comment: Then try $mail->getBodyHtml(); templates are not automatically added as plain text